# WPF/MVVM - Navigation patterns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have decided, after our senior developer at my workplace has used WinForms since I-don't-even-know-how-long, to try and use WPF for our next project... so I'm trying to study its basics as even though I know how it works, I have never used it in practice.

So I'm stumped with a very, very basic concept that, in WinForms, is basically a simpleton: opening a Window from another.

Oh, yes.

You know, MVVM and its abstractions. So... I have tried to research the subject of navigating between ViewModels in WPF so the logic is still separated as it's meant to. It's an extremely confusing topic though, that feels unnecessarily complex - at least, in Xamarin/MAUI, frameworks like FreshMVVM handle that part in non-complicated ways...

What's the best practice for handling navigation in WPF/MVVM? I've read multiple suggestions ranging from Dependency Injection to just breaking the MVVM pattern and referencing the Views through the ViewModels... and it's all quite confusing.

Comment: Yep, there are multiple options and asking "which is best" can't necessarily bring any fruitful answers. One of the reasons MVVM was not that widely adopted as one could expect, is that things that should be simple can be confusing and have multiple valid approaches none of which feel really "simple".

Comment: Oh it's nice to see there's someone else that also feels the same! I just keep reading MVVM is integral to WPF and I don't really understand why, as it's just made simple things confusing for no particular reason... 

I'm not really asking "which is best", I'm asking which one I should use! But I guess I can just skip the whole MVVM thing for now...

Comment: MVVM does in no way dictate that a window has somehow magically to be opened by a view model. There is nothing that stops you from implementing MVVM and still open a window e.g. in a click event handler of a child element of another window, i.e. in the vbiew code.

Comment: "...skip the whole MVVM thing for now..."
Don't... it will bite you in the ass...
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet-architecture/eBooks/main/current/maui/Enterprise-Application-Patterns-Using-.NET-MAUI.pdf

Comment: @Clemens Sure, fine, but what if, for example, I want to open a window that gets values from the main window? Like let's say for example one window contains a gridview with data and I want to get the data row on the other window so I can edit its values. I would have to somehow pass that to the ViewModel, no?

Comment: The main window passes an appropriate view model instance to the child window by setting its DataContext property.

Comment: @F.Bill I have an example for you [@github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-76388000-WpfMultipleWindows) - I moved some ideas from MAUI to WPF, maybe you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it's an MVVM-related question. MVVM does not solve navigation in WPF in any way.

There are many ways to tackle navigation in WPF. The one that I've been using for quite some time (and is using MVVM) is this:

1. Have a main view + main view model.
2. The main view model contains a property called "CurrentView," which can be of any type that suits your needs. It could be just an object or an interface that you implement in the other view models you want to navigate to. This property holds your current view model.
3. Place a ContentControl inside your main view and bind its content to the CurrentView property from your main view model.
4. Create a DataTemplate for each of your views.

That's it. Every time the value of CurrentView changes, the ContentControl will load the appropriate DataTemplate.

Comment: But that addresses not the question: *opening a Window from another*